# Python 3.7 BeautifullSoup soup.find error - find() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I had the below HTML from URL:

```
<h4>
   \r\n                            \r\n\r\n
   <a href="/l">
      \r\n    <!-- mp_trans_rt_start id="1" args="as" 1 -->\r\n    <span class="brandWrapTitle">\r\n        <span class="productdescriptionbrand">Mxxx</span>\r\n    </span>\r\n    <span class="nameWrapTitle">\r\n        <span class="productdescriptionname">Axxxname</span>\r\n    </span>\r\n    <!-- mp_trans_rt_end 1 -->\r\n
   </a>
   \r\n\r\n                        
</h4>
```

And im trying to use python to find  class name:

```
  import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://link"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
urlwithagent = urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(urlwithagent)
soup = response.read()
product = soup.find("h4", attrs ={"class=": "productdescriptionname"})
print (product)
```

Everythink works perfect until line :

```
product = soup.find("h4", attrs ={"class=": "productdescriptionname"})
```

Im getting error like:

```
find() takes no keyword arguments
```

And I had no idea how to fix it - there is lot of info around but nothing works :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert it to a `BeautifulSoup` object before using `find` or else it uses `str.find`

**Ex:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), "html.parser")
product = soup.find("h4", attrs ={"class": "productdescriptionname"})
print (product)
```

Comment: `"class="` should be `"class"`

Comment: @DeepSpace. Thanks. Did not see that

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be worth mentioning, if having problems with `find` method, checking `type(soup)` is a good way to find out if you're working with the correct `bs4.BeautifulSoup` object and not `str`.

One thing I'd like to point here, if using `soup.prettify()` to make the `html` readable. It is important to note that `.prettify()` converts the `bs4.BeautifulSoup` to `str`. So this should be used separately like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response) # type(soup) --> bs4.BeautifulSoup
print(soup.prettify()) # print readable html
```

And not like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response).prettify() # type(soup) --> str
```

One more thing that I read online regarding this issue was something like *"Your version of beautiful soup might not support find."* Hence, I ended up upgrading and degrading the version quite a few times before realising that it was a false statement made by someone amateur.

I had been struggling for about 45 minutes with just this before printing `type(soup)`. I hope this saves someones else their time.