# Python beautiful soup TypeError : find() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I try find_all I get that error  AttributeError:

> 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 

    url = "https://www.gittigidiyor.com/bilgisayar-tablet/huawei-matebook-d-14-amd-53010wpx-dizustu-bilgisayar-laptop_pdp_555531393"

    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")
    data = soup.find("div", attrs = {"class":"gg-w-24 gg-d-24 gg-t-24 gg-m-24 padding-none-m"})

    for i in data:
        price = i.find("div", attrs = {"id":"sp-price-lowPrice"})
        print(price.text)
```

Comment: Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71099160/12648789) answer to verify that you're working with correct `bs4.BeautifulSoup` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one item with class "gg-w-24 gg-d-24 gg-t-24 gg-m-24 padding-none-m" and only one item with id "sp-price-lowPrice" on that page. As such why not simply do:

```
price = soup.find("div", attrs = {"id":"sp-price-lowPrice"})
```

If you do expect multiple items having "gg-w-24 gg-d-24 gg-t-24 gg-m-24 padding-none-m", then amend data to:

```
data = soup.find_all("div", attrs = {"class":"gg-w-24 gg-d-24 gg-t-24 gg-m-24 padding-none-m"})
# for i in data: 
#... rest of your code here
```